# Contemporary typeface(s) similar to Bodoni for short titles and headlines

Tags: font-recommendation, typefaces

I have been playing with Vidaloka from Google Fonts, but also looking to try out a commercial alternative before I recommend an update to a client.

To add to my reasoning and avoid making the request too broad, I would be fine with using Bodoni, but I am trying to locate something similar with a more contemporary touch if anything like that exists.

Another reason is I'd rather avoid these super classic typefaces everyone else is praising (for good reasons) and be open to newer designs with a similar feel, at the same time supporting younger type designers if possible.

Another reason is the client doesn't mind spending on assets, so I'd rather not use free stuff if I can get quality stuff.

[image]

Comment: And why the close votes?  How is this opinion based, while this  other 100k views, 19 upvotes question is *not* opinion based? I see alot of opinions there!! :) https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/602

Comment: I didn't close vote and I agree with you it's not opinion based at all; Bodoni is Bodoni and has very specific features. That said, I think the question could benefit a bit more context to be less broad (e.g. Why do you want to avoid Bodoni? Is there a particular glyph or feature that irks you and would want to avoid? Reading into your wish to update for a client...Do you want something a bit more modern but with the same feel?)

Comment: Edited. Thanks and really appreciate your answer, hopefully some more ideas will pop up.

Comment: What do you mean by "More contemporary?"

Comment: I'll update my answer in a bit. Can you also say what your use will be? I wouldn't recommend the same thing for main text vs. titles or a logotype foundation for example...

Comment: Short titles and headlines mainly.

Comment: @Lucian I was writing my updated answer in the meantime but considering that information, I wouldn't change my answer :)

Comment: @Lucian Funny this [one](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/35613/webfont-alternatives-to-gotham) just cropped up on the front page :) 113K views too!

Comment: Oh no! That can't be opinion based, can it?! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first that comes to mind is [Didot](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/didot/).

[image]

I find Identifont "Font by Similarity" is a great tool to find similar fonts, just type your font and look for the similar .
[http://www.identifont.com/find?font=bodoni&q=Go](http://www.identifont.com/find?similar=bodoni&q=Go)

If you want something with the same general feel but not exactly, I would go for a search by family tag in myfonts.com, in this case "[Didone](http://www.myfonts.com/search/tag%3ADidone/fonts/)":

If you want [something like Bodoni but with an added feature or two](http://www.identifont.com/identify.html), it's sometimes possible to trick Identifont into giving you results tailored to what you want by answering questions on each specific feature.

ETA:

> newer designs with a similar feel, at the same time supporting younger
>   type designers if possible.

If 3 weights is sufficient for your needs and a bit of a condensed look doesn't bother you, I would like to recommend the [Voga](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/cdtype/voga/) designed in 2014 by Charles Daoud. He is a great new type designer who is local to me and has tackled exclusive mandates for Radio-Canada (our national broadcaster) and NetFlix among others. Some of the glyphs are really beautiful.

[Images linked from his Behance](https://www.behance.net/gallery/19360047/Voga-typeface) below (do click the link, it shows way more than the size that is allowed it seems). Check out those G/g/s/Q/W/0.

> It has an extensive glyph set that supports languages for the Americas
>   and most of Europe.

And stylistic alternates as well.

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]